# Can a C# method define a variable number of object parameters, and a variable number on integer parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, tuples

**Can a C# method define a variable number of object parameters, and a variable number on integer parameters, in this simple way, or some other simple way for the caller?**

*What does simple mean?*
Simple as seen from the callers perspective. Prioritizing least amount typing/characters required, and easy to understand and use.

*For what purpose?*
The motivation is a basic wrapper for Console.WriteLine that makes it easier to output columned text. The existing notation is not intuitive (for ex, it requires negative numbers). It's also more verbose than needed for some basic scenarios.

**One answer that seems ideal, if it's possible, would show how to define a method like this using two tuples, each tuple with n values (or hey, just up to say, 10 values). The thinking is it could reduce the caller code to this:**

```
// Output items given column widths
Console.WriteCols(("Name", "Address", "Age"), (20, 10, 30))
Console.WriteCols(("John", "123 Street", 28), (20, 10, 30))
Console.WriteCols(("Mary", "456 Street"), (20, 10))
```

I know it's just a list of values, but that would fit most of our column use cases, and moreover, if the first example is possible, it seems string variables could be added later if needed, like:

```
Console.WriteCols(("{0} John", "123 Street", 28), (20, 10, 30), ("Dr."))
```

*Fine go do it, what's the problem?*
For the first basic example, I've tried a few approaches. One sticking point is I don't see a way to get a count of values for a Tuple.  Maybe it's staring me in the face, or I'm over complicating this.  The first idea was to just create method overloads with 2 Tuples that allow up to 10 values for each tuple. Then all overloads would call a primary method to do the work.  However, if the primary method is receiving loosely typed tuples with varying numbers of items, it was not clear how to handle all the overload cases in a generalized way, if the count of tuple values can't be known.

Comment: It *sounds like* you're looking for `params`, but I'm pretty sure there can be only one of those per method signature.  Why not pass lists/arrays to the method?

Comment: So you want `Console.WriteLine` to group your data?What´s your problem os using `String.Format`?

Comment: Accept arrays, not tuples.

Comment: Well, you can use `params object[]` and sort the types out yourself, including validation that the number of arguments must be even, and all strings come before all ints. A parameter object might be a better approach, though.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this. Just decide on the least likely scenario for number of columns you wish to make "easy", then create overrides starting at one object and one column width, incrementing the number of arguments until you get to your max. Then provide for a generic method that takes an array of objects and an array of ints to handle anything greater.

Comment: How does the third example (`"Mary"`)  fit the two above? Should the third (last) column be empty in this case, meaning she has no age?

Comment: Another option is to have a method `Write` that takes `params object[] args` and returns an object that has a method named `Columns`, which has a reference to those args, and takes `params int[] args` and writes the whole thing via Console.Write.

Comment: @David, you're right that's possible, it's just that initializing array literals are more verbose (less simple as simple is defined above) than the sample format in the example i.e. Console.WriteCols(("Name", "Address", "Age"), (20, 10, 30))

Comment: @Will sounds great, I would like to do that.  In the last paragraph I explain the problem I encountered when trying it.  Maybe it's a dumb mistake I'm making?

Comment: @Lee: Defining your own C# syntax seems like it's going to make things *a bit* more complicated than using a few more keystrokes in the existing syntax.

Comment: @HimBromBeere.  Yes, your assumption is exactly correct.  That line was just meant the illustrate the need to allow a variable number of parameters, even if variable is a smallish finite number.

Comment: @David, (edit: think I missed a point, don't see how it can be done with less characters than my example, continuing to original comment...)   It's subjective of course, so I'm open to that possibility and to your input on pros/cons.  Beyond the subjective part that the example seems intuitive to my biased view, the objective reasons were it's less characters and less typing, and also that I know a few experienced c# programmers who sometimes still have to google array literal initialization forms, guess they stick in some brains easier than others.

Comment: If you can target .NET 4.7.1 - there is public `ITuple` interface which all tuples implement. That will allow you to define 10 overloads with variable number of arguments and handle them all in generic way. Though to be honest I prefer solution provided in Ed Plunkett's answer.

Comment: @HimBromBeere on why not use String.Format: As far as I'm aware, using String.Format would not be as simple using the examples given, under the definition of simple described above.  But if it can, I'd love to use it, that would be great.

Comment: @Amy, the reason for not using arrays is because it would not be a simple for the caller.  See my last comment to David, and how simple is being defined for this problem.  thank you.

Comment: @Joey, that would be a nice solution, but whenever it seems like there would be cases that made it impossible to disambiguate the values from the column widths.  For example, how to interpret this: Console.WriteCols(10,20,30,40,50,60,70)?

Comment: @Evk Awesome, somehow I didn't find that, but is has the length parameter to make generic handling possible.  As for Ed's solution I'm taking a look next.  thank you.

Comment: Wish I could understand why this question was downvoted because I've read and responded to all comments and don't get it for the life of me what's wrong with seeking a way to define a simple client interface.  Even if someone didn't like my example I was explicit in being open to other possibilities.

Comment: Ed's solution has big advantage over your proposed syntax - you define column widths only once, and then you just write values without specifying widths again and again, reducing possibility of mistake (and overall repeating same values multiple times is not quite a good design).

Comment: @Evk so what if it's better?  That's great, because that was the point of the question, to find the best way to do it.  If I thought my example was some final word on how people should code, I would have simply asked how to get find the number of elements in a Tuple to get past my roadblock in my experiment.  I didn't ask only about Tuple count, specifically because I expected the community might have better approaches.

Comment: That was not a reply about why you get downvoted, I actually upvoted question. Just a note about that solution.

Comment: @Evk then please forgive my confusion.  I appreciate your feedback and the helpful comment pointing out iTuple. I have upvoted all of your comments to try and help reflect their value.

Comment: @Evk separate point on repeating widths being bad design - believe it or not that was on purpose.  The thinking being there would have to be a stateful approach like instantiating an object, to avoid repetition, but that the all in one line static approach was still important for one off usage where it would be preferrable to not maintain object variables.  The beauty of the accepted answer is that is solves both at once - dry principles are respected, while not requiring any additional stray object variables to clutter things up.  It's all neatly hidden, yet without being opaque.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static class MyConsole
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        Console.Out
            .Columns(10, 40, 60)
            .WriteLine("foo", "bar", "baz")
            .WriteLine("LOL", "WUT", "BBQ")
            .WriteLine("HA", "ha", "ha");

        var cols = Console.Error.Columns(10, 40, 30);

        cols.WriteLine("Mary", "Had", "a");
        cols.WriteLine("Little", "lamb", "it's");
    }

    public static ColumnWriter Columns(params int[] widths) => new ColumnWriter(Console.Out, widths);
    public static ColumnWriter Columns(this TextWriter writer, params int[] widths) => new ColumnWriter(writer, widths);

    public class ColumnWriter
    {
        public ColumnWriter(TextWriter writer, int[] widths)
        {
            Debug.Assert(writer != null);
            Debug.Assert(widths != null);

            _writer = writer;
            _widths = widths;
        }
        private TextWriter _writer;
        private int[] _widths;

        public ColumnWriter Line()
        {
            _writer.WriteLine();
            return this;
        }

        public ColumnWriter Write(params object[] args)
        {
            Debug.Assert(args.Length == _widths.Length);

            var count = Math.Min(_widths.Length, args.Length);
            for (int idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx)
            {
                var fmt = "{0," + _widths[idx] + "}";
                _writer.Write(fmt, args[idx]);
            }

            return this;
        }
        public ColumnWriter WriteLine(params object[] args)
        {
            return Write(args).Line();
        }
    }
}
```

This could be improved by adding overloads for `Columns(string formatString)` and `Columns(this TextWriter writer, string formatString)`.

---

### Bad ideas

Columns() can be made to return a delegate, for some odd looking syntax (thanks Evk for showing me the way -- and for not liking the syntax any better than I do). Worse yet, we can give it multiple indexer overloads.

I don't like the novel syntax in either case. This works, but anybody who'd use either one in production code would steal sheep:

```
public static class MyConsole
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        //  Not a great idea.
        MyConsole.WriteLines(10, 10)("foo", "bar")("baz", "planxty");

        //  Truly awful idea.
        MyConsole.Columns(10, 10)["foo", "bar"]["baz", "planxty"].End();
    }

    public static ColumnWriter Columns(params int[] widths) => new ColumnWriter(widths);

    #region Not a great idea
    //  Evk showed me how to make this work. 
    public delegate Params Params(params object[] values);
    public static Params WriteLines(params int[] widths)
    {
        var writer = new ColumnWriter(widths);

        return new Params(writer.WriteLineParams);
    }
    #endregion Not a great idea

    public class ColumnWriter
    {
        public ColumnWriter(int[] widths)
        {
            _widths = widths;
        }
        private int[] _widths;

        #region Truly awful idea.
        public ColumnWriter this[object o] => WriteLine(o);
        public ColumnWriter this[object o1, object o2] => WriteLine(o1, o2);
        public ColumnWriter this[object o1, object o2, object o3] => WriteLine(o1, o2, o3);

        //  ...moar overloards...

        //  In C# x[0]; is an expression, not a statement. 
        //  x[0].End(); is a statement. Horrible, most horrible. 
        //  Maybe I should name it FireMe() instead of End()
        public void End() { }
        #endregion Truly awful idea.

        public ColumnWriter Line()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            return this;
        }

        public ColumnWriter Write(params object[] args)
        {
            var count = Math.Min(_widths.Length, args.Length);
            for (int idx = 0; idx < count; ++idx)
            {
                var fmt = "{0," + _widths[idx] + "}";
                Console.Write(fmt, args[idx]);
            }

            return this;
        }
        public ColumnWriter WriteLine(params object[] args) 
            => Write(args).Line();

        #region Not a great idea
        public Params WriteLineParams(params object[] args)
        {
            WriteLine(args);

            return WriteLineParams;
        }
        #endregion Not a great idea
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be good to make `Write` return this (`ColumnWriter`), to allow chaining the whole thing.

Comment: @Evk Right you are. Thanks. Done.

Comment: "I'd like to find a way to have Columns() return a delegate" - you can do it. Define `public delegate void Params(params object[] values);` and change signature to `public static Params Columns(params int[] widths)`. You can even define delegate like this: `public delegate Params Params(params object[] values);` and then you will be able to chain invocations: `MyConsole.Columns(1,2)("bla")("bla2")`

Comment: @Evk You should add that as your own answer so I can upvote you.

Comment: I don't quite like the resulting syntax to be honest :)

Comment: @Evk I don't like the syntax one bit either, but it's cool that it works.

Comment: I've been meaning for years to write a blog article about this sort of technique. After 40+ years of the awfulness that is printf and its successors we are all adapted to believing that formatting means writing modem line noise into the middle of strings. Formatting can be done in a more principled manner with combinators.

Comment: @Evk and Ed, just catching up to this answer.  Which of these are you guys saying you don't like?  I've marked the answer correct because the first chainable example seems simple and elegant.  Not sure what the concern around it is.    MyConsole.Columns(10, 40, 60).WriteLine("foo", "bar", "baz")

Comment: @Lee First example is good. The rest (under "Bad ideas" section) are not.

Comment: @Lee I like the one you just quoted. I don't like `MyConsole.Columns(10)("foo")("bar")` -- the chain of argument lists is the kind of "WTF?" nobody should have to figure out when they're reading my code. The one with the indexer overloads was just a party trick.

Comment: @EricLippert it's quite pity in general that posts to your blog are so rare last time (last is of March this year).

Comment: @Lee Also, the object chaining allows `cols.Write("foo", "bar").Line()`, which isn't very exciting in itself, but it suggests further possibilities. Chaining the delegate, you're stuck with calling the same method over and over.

Comment: @EricLippert that'd be great to see, agree there's low hanging fruit improvements that somehow haven't yet become canonical. Libraries like chalk have become very popular, and to their credit can be very useful, but it's still not hard to see past it (thanks hindsight), or how we could all have more/better options.  Off-topic, by chance it seems we may have worked at the same company partially at the same time, and also lived near each other in another country partially at the same time.  Small world.

Comment: @Evk: I have been *extremely* busy at work this year, and also editing Jon's and Mark's books; sadly, something had to give. Hopefully I'll get back into it next year.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two lists, one of type `string` and a second of type `int`. For further parameters (e.g. formatters) you can then add the `params` keyword:

```
WriteCols(List<string> cols, List<int> width, params string[] formatters)
{
    if(cols.Count != widths.Count) throw new ArgumentException("Paramater-counts not matching");

    foreach(var e in cols)
        Console.Write(/* add some padding so that every column has the desired width */ String.Format(e, formatters));
}
```

Comment: This is really a better way to do it.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, I'm guessing you're thinking "better" means easier to implement.  If so, yes that's definitely true.  However the goal in this case is to optimize the caller experience, without regard to whether or not an internal implementation has to do more work.  If you look at my caller examples and definition of simple it explains.  However, even so I understand you still may prefer explicit array literal initialization syntax and I respect that option.  It just doesn't appear as clean to me, and the extra work on the back end is worth it for us in this particular case.

Comment: IMHO *Optimiz(ing) the caller experience* doesn't not include creating a weird syntax that no programmer will intuitively get.  This means that this *caller experience* requires [Tribal Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribal_knowledge).  Knowledge that is only useful in this instance and not useful to the caller outside the current application or at any other company.  I would suggest not making any personal references to my preferences, especially when you don't know me which makes sounds like you're taking it personal.

Comment: While it may not be *clean*, that's a personal preference.  I myself do not subscribe to writing code to personal preferences but to write code that is easy to read, easy to maintain.  When a widely accepted new pattern merges (for example Fluent API) I'm mostly onboard (for me its always dependent on if it's pro's outweigh the cons, always excluding personal preference).

Comment: @ErikPhilips you've somehow inferred a polite critical response means things that do not relate to what I'm saying.  Referring to preference in subjective matters is not a personal affront, and I don't think you'll find many computer science people who believe designing functions or apis is a purely objective process.  Finally, it's difficult to argue a syntax is "weird", if it was intentionally introduced as a feature and meant to be used unexceptionally in that way in the language.  Less familiar, granted.